# sk-learn like model

Tags: python, object-oriented, machine-learning

I am trying to make a simple model that returns the conditional expectation of a target with respect to the value observed for another variable.

Basically, given a feature \$F\$, a level of this feature \$f\$, and a target \$y\$, the predicted value is:

$$p=\mathbb{E}[y|F=f]$$

As much as possible, I tried to follow sk-learns signatures and methods. How could I improve the readability of the code?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


class ConditionalExpectation:

    def __init__(self, feature_name, rare_threshold=10, verbose=False):
        self._feature_name = feature_name
        self._rare_name = "__RARE__"
        self._target_name = "__TARGET__"
        self._rare_threshold = rare_threshold
        self._verbose = verbose

    def fit(self, train, target):
        feat = self._feature_name

        self.train = train.copy()
        self.train[self._target_name] = target
        self._average = target.mean()

        self._rare_values = self.train[feat].value_counts()[self.train[feat]].values < self._rare_threshold

        self.train.loc[self._rare_values, feat] = self._rare_name
        self.train.loc[self.train[feat].value_counts()[self.train[feat]].values < self._rare_threshold, feat] = self._rare_name

        self._means = self.train.groupby([feat])[self._target_name].mean()
        self._means[self._rare_name] = self._average

        if(self._verbose):
            print("Observed : " + str(len(self._means)) + " categories for variable : " + self._feature_name + ".")

        del self.train[self._target_name]
        return self

    def predict(self, test):
        feat = self._feature_name

        test = test.copy()
        test.loc[self._rare_values, feat] = self._rare_name
        criterion = ~test[feat].isin(set(self.train[feat]))
        test.loc[criterion, feat] = self._average

        return test[feat].replace(self._means, inplace=False)

    def predict_proba(self, test):
        return predict(self, test)

    def get_params(self, deep=True):
        return {"feature_name": self._feature_name, "rare_threshold": self._rare_threshold}
```

Comment: Why did you use `predict_proba()` if it just calls the same `predict()` without changes?

Comment: @Vasyalisk I have cross validation loops for classification (resp. regression) that rely on predict_proba() (resp. predict())